# How to Call Vibrator inside a Service in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, android-vibration

I am trying to run the `vibrator` if service is called from my app.I am starting the service from `Fragment` but i don't know why vibrator is not working inside the service.I couldn't even print the `Toast`.My code:

**Calling from Fragment:**

```
Intent buzz= new Intent(getActivity(),LocBuzzService.class);
   getActivity().startService(buzz);
```

**Service class:**

```
public class LocBuzzService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "HelloService";
    private boolean isRunning  = false;
    public Vibrator vibrator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Log.i(TAG, "I am in thread");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"I am here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    vibrator.vibrate(3000);
                    vibrator.cancel();

                }catch (Exception e){

                }

                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();


        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

I have also tried this and didn't work:

```
  vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

I saw in logcat that every function inside the service class are called and i have also included the permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: does an exception occur in the `catch` block?

Comment: Why are you cancelling it right after calling vibrate()?

Comment: I want to run the vibrator for 3 seconds and then cancel it

Comment: Remove that line. The call to vibrate(3000) is not blocking, so it's causing the vibration to be cancelled before it even starts. The vibration will be "finished" after 3000, no need to cancel it

Comment: Beyond that, **never** catch an exception without logging it, particularly when you are debugging an app.

Comment: I have cancelled that line but not working though..

Comment: It worked when i delete the Toast..How can i print the Toast in a service??

Comment: The Toast call needs to be done on the Main thread. The fact you were not logging the exception didn't help, as im pretty sure an Exception was being thrown

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.mani.smsdetect;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class SampleService extends Service{

    Vibrator vibrator;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }


}
```

Add vibrator permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```