# I want it to vibrate when I click the button

Tags: android, kotlin

I want the phone to vibrate when I click the button

I want to do this with Kotlin in Android Studio

The following code did not work

```
val vib = getSystemService(MainActivity.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
val milliseconds:Long = 2000
vib.vibrate(milliseconds)
```

Comment: Is there something interesting in the log output? Have you given your app vibration permissions?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005055/how-to-call-vibrator-inside-a-service-in-android)?

Comment: or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52273785/1401808) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add vibrator permission to `AndroidManifest.xml:`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

then..

```
val vibrator:Vibrator
vibrator = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
vibrator.vibrate(100)
```